# Ionic 4 Angular template binding with async pipe to observable

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am moving an old ionic app from V2 to V4-alpha and am unable to bind in template to an observable using async pipe. The issue arises by having an *ngFor on an element nested inside another element with an *ngIf. The table displays fine when not using the *ngIf, but does not display data table when *ngIf is included and is used to switch between different data tables.

In component:

```
this.indLbdPlayers = this.fsService.getPlayersByIndScore(id);
this.indLbdPlayers.subscribe(players => {
  this.indArray = players;
});
```

where

```
indLbdPlayers: Observable<HSPlayer[]>;
indArray: HSPlayer[];
```

In template:

`<div *ngIf="!showTeamLbd">
    <table>
    ...
    <tr *ngFor="let player of indLbdPlayers | async; let ro = odd; let i = index;"`

does not display anything. However, when use this in template:

`<div *ngIf="!showTeamLbd">
    <table>
    ...
    <tr *ngFor="let player of indArray; let ro = odd; let i = index;" let ro = odd;`

i.e. w/out async pipe to observable but subscribing to observable in component, then the array displays as expected.

From ionic info:

cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

@ionic/cli-utils  : 2.0.0-rc.6
   ionic (Ionic CLI) : 4.0.0-rc.6

global packages:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0

local packages:

@angular-devkit/core       : 0.6.0

@angular-devkit/schematics : 0.6.0

@angular/cli               : 6.0.1

@ionic/schematics-angular  : 1.0.0-rc.6

Cordova Platforms          : none

Ionic Framework            : @ionic/angular 4.0.0-alpha.7

Answer (score 0):

Try with this,

```
  *ngFor="let player of (indLbdPlayers | async)"; let ro = odd; let i = index;"
```

Comment: Thanks, but that makes no difference. My observable is coming from Angularfire2 where I query Firestore. I have a sibling app that is pure Angular (6.0.X) that performs similar queries of same database and the async pipe renders as expected. I hope it's something simple, but I'm getting concerned it's more fundamental to ionic/angular v4.

Comment: Updated the question above - this issue appears to be related to the *ngFor being nested inside *ngIf, even though on a different element.